# JavaScript: Cut out Array of Strings until a certain String matches (the elegant way)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Lets assume I have the following array:

```
const arr = [ '0', 'parentNode', 'children', '0', 'values' ]
```

And my goal is to cut the array until when a certain string matches (everything **after** that string).

So if I choose **children** as the string, the result would be:

```
const arr = [ '0', 'parentNode', 'children']
```

My current implementation works, I am creating a big function and iterating over the array, push each element to a new array when a condition holds....

But I would like to have a more elegant solution, maybe a oneliner.

In Python, this is possible, how would this look like in JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways.

[`indexof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) ([`findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) if you need to use a callback because the comparison is more complicated) and [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
const index = arr.indexOf(target);
const result = index < 0 ? [] : arr.slice(index);
```

A simple loop:

```
const result = [];
let found = false;
for (const element of arr) {
    found = found || element === target;
    if (found) {
        result.push(element);
    }
}
```

[`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
let found = false;
const result = arr.filter(element => {
    found = found || element === target;
    return found;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the one-liner solution:

`arr.slice(0, arr.indexOf('children') + 1)`

It performs well, because uses native code (V8, SpiderMonkey, etc...). But does not handle errors. If no `'children'` is found, you'll receive empty array.